# How should I setup this polygon hair node material in blender?

Tags: hair

[image]

This was made by [Sieng JeongHo,](https://www.artstation.com/nefred)   as a tutorial on how to texture polygon hair in marmoset toolbag. But I was wondering how could I recreate this in blender cycles? How should I setup the nodes and which ones should I use?